# Develop Spring Boot API to get response based on range

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm learning Java and as part of it, trying to develop a Spring Boot API that communicates with MongoDB Atlas cluster. I'm trying to write an API that would return items based on the price range value where min and max values are provided dynamically. Please help me understand where am I doing a mistake by going through the code below. I strongly feel it has to do with `@Query` and `@PathVariable`, I feel `@RequestParam` should be used in place of `@PathVariable`, however, I'm not sure what to use in place of `@Query` in the repository.

Here is the code of the repository

```java
package com.webshoppingbackend.springboot.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;

import com.webshoppingbackend.springboot.model.WebShoppingItem;

public interface WebShoppingRepository extends MongoRepository<WebShoppingItem, String> {

    @Query("{category:?0}")
    List<WebShoppingItem> getItemsByCategory(String category);

    @Query("{brand:?0}")
    List<WebShoppingItem> getItemsByBrand(String brand);

    @Query("{price:{$lt:?0,$gt:?1}}")
    List<WebShoppingItem> getItemsBasedOnPrice(long higherPrice, long lowerPrice);

}
```

Here is the code of the controller

```java
package com.webshoppingbackend.springboot.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.webshoppingbackend.springboot.model.WebShoppingItem;
import com.webshoppingbackend.springboot.services.WebShoppingService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/webshopping")
public class WebShoppingController {
    @Autowired
    private WebShoppingService service;

    @GetMapping
    public List<WebShoppingItem> getAllItems() {
        return service.getWebShoppingItems();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{itemId}")
    public WebShoppingItem getItem(@PathVariable String itemId) {
        return service.getItemById(itemId);
    }

    @GetMapping("/category/{category}")
    public List<WebShoppingItem> getItemsByCategory(@PathVariable String category) {
        return service.getItemsByCategory(category);
    }

    @GetMapping("/brand/{brand}")
    public List<WebShoppingItem> getItemsByBrand(@PathVariable String brand) {
        return service.getItemsByBrand(brand);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{price}")
    public List<WebShoppingItem> getItemsBasedOnPriceRange(@PathVariable long higherPrice,
            @PathVariable long lowerPrice) {
        return service.getItemsBasedOnPriceRange(higherPrice, lowerPrice);
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public WebShoppingItem addItem(@RequestBody WebShoppingItem webShoppingItem) {
        return service.addToWebShoppingItems(webShoppingItem);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public WebShoppingItem modifyItem(@RequestBody WebShoppingItem webShoppingItem) {
        return service.updateWebShoppingItem(webShoppingItem);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{itemId}")
    public String deleteItem(@PathVariable String itemId) {
        return service.deleteWebShoppingItem(itemId);
    }
}
```

Here is the code in the service provider

```java
package com.webshoppingbackend.springboot.services;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.webshoppingbackend.springboot.model.WebShoppingItem;
import com.webshoppingbackend.springboot.repository.WebShoppingRepository;

@Service
public class WebShoppingService {
    @Autowired
    private WebShoppingRepository repository;

    // CRUD

    public WebShoppingItem addToWebShoppingItems(WebShoppingItem webShoppingItem) {
        webShoppingItem.setItemId(UUID.randomUUID().toString().split("-")[0]);
        return repository.save(webShoppingItem);
    }

    public List<WebShoppingItem> getWebShoppingItems() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public WebShoppingItem getItemById(String itemId) {
        return repository.findById(itemId).get();
    }

    public List<WebShoppingItem> getItemsByCategory(String category) {
        return repository.getItemsByCategory(category);
    }

    public List<WebShoppingItem> getItemsByBrand(String brand) {
        return repository.getItemsByBrand(brand);
    }

    public List<WebShoppingItem> getItemsBasedOnPriceRange(long higherPrice, long lowerPrice) {
        return repository.getItemsBasedOnPrice(higherPrice, lowerPrice);
    }

    public WebShoppingItem updateWebShoppingItem(WebShoppingItem webShoppingItem) {
        WebShoppingItem itemToBeUpdated = repository.findById(webShoppingItem.getItemId()).get();
        itemToBeUpdated.setCategory(webShoppingItem.getCategory());
        itemToBeUpdated.setProductName(webShoppingItem.getProductName());
        itemToBeUpdated.setImageSource(webShoppingItem.getImageSource());
        itemToBeUpdated.setBrand(webShoppingItem.getBrand());
        itemToBeUpdated.setPrice(webShoppingItem.getPrice());
        itemToBeUpdated.setRating(webShoppingItem.getRating());
        itemToBeUpdated.setShippingCharges(webShoppingItem.getShippingCharges());
        itemToBeUpdated.setProductDetails(webShoppingItem.getProductDetails());
        return repository.save(itemToBeUpdated);
    }

    public String deleteWebShoppingItem(String itemId) {
        repository.deleteById(itemId);
        return "Deleted Web Shopping Item";
    }
}
```

Here is the request I'm sending through Talend API Tester to test my code.
[image]

Comment: higherPrice and lowerPrice should be @RequestParam. Your URI should be like /webshopping/items?higerPrice=90000&lowerPrice=0

Comment: In controller use, @GetMapping("/items") and similarly modify other methods as well.